# Creating project in 6.0 results in no repository

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to create a new project in 6.0.  Gitlab says that repository was created successfully, but there is no repository created.   When I push a repository to it, git fails with:

fatal: '/home/git/repositories/mmacrae/test.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Pushing and Pulling to existing repo's is working fine via both http and ssh.

The only error I could find in log files is in sidekiq.log:

2013-08-26T16:24:33Z 4564 TID-gdw1s GitlabShellWorker JID-1e462235fc0d2f8e879f1198 INFO: start
2013-08-26T16:24:33Z 4564 TID-gg9cw GitlabShellWorker JID-fd57c54d46807ab9cad97b55 INFO: start
: No such file or directory
2013-08-26T16:24:33Z 4564 TID-gdw1s GitlabShellWorker JID-1e462235fc0d2f8e879f1198 INFO: done: 0.016 sec
: No such file or directory

Comment: What do the checks say? Is sidekiq running? Does the `git` user has write access to the repo path? The repo folder is actually created while the first push.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: It turned out to be stale or corrupt source files in gitlab-shell.  For some reason a bunch of files were showing as modified.  I fixed this by running:  `sudo -u git -H git --reset hard` in the gitlab-shell directory to get back to the versions in the repo (v1.7.0).  Unfortunately, I wasn't able to catch what was different about them that caused the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I fixed it with a reboot of the system. My guess was a shell hook wasn't re-initialized.

Comment: Or sidekiq wasn't running.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not in a situation that allows you to reboot things, you can manually create a bare repository:

```
sudo su git
cd git/repositories/{namespace}
mkdir {project name} && cd $_
git --bare init
```

It wouldn't hurt, after, to:

```
cd ~/gitlab
bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
```

…and see what that tells you. It will likely warn you that you need to create satellites, so do that, too:

```
bundle exec rake gitlab:satellites:create RAILS_ENV=production
```