# GitLab does not create new repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, gitlab

The issue occurs when creating a repository in  gitlab and then pushing to the repository.

```
git remote add gitlab git@git.metacloud.ca:mike.ch/helloworld.git
git push -u gitlab master

result:
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I checked the repository folder in the gitlab home.
it creates the helloworld.wiki.git files but not the helloworld.git

I have seen multiple posts on this issue and I have tried the following solutions.

[Creating project in 6.0 results in no repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448783/creating-project-in-6-0-results-in-no-repository)
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production
sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

I have seen the errors fixed them and then rebooted the server.

Still this does not appear to work created more projects.

Anyone have a solution ? I am pretty much all out of ideas

```
GitLab 6.4.3

GitLab Shell 1.7.9

GitLab API v3

Ruby 2.0.0p247

Rails 4.0.2
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Have you added the correct ssh key to your user account? You can test if this is working by trying to connect via ssh (ssh git@your-gitlab-host.tld), which should log you in, welcome you and then terminate the connection directly.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, it all works on that end, there are no issues communicating with the server by cloning by ssh the credentials all work out,

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-public-wiki/wiki/Trouble-Shooting-Guide#gitlab-shell ?

Comment: Okay I figured it out it was a bug due to a lock file messing up the dependency issue with Gems.... its a bug reported. anyways it was fixed

Comment: Don't support you remember which lock file or files it was?  If you do, could you add an answer explaining how you recovered from it?  I'm suffering from the same problem right now.

Comment: Uh.. that is.. "Don't _suppose_ you remember ...".. :)